# Storyboard: Custom UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, tableview

I use Storyboard in my project.

If I **used** a `h.-File` my code **would be**:

```
IImage * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"];
UIImageView * backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
```

Is there a way to do these customizations just in Interface Builder?

I guess not.

**So my second question is**, if I use code, how can I keep the `Static cells` and the `navigation segues` I made in Interface Builder? Just leaving out the delegate methods would be nonsense.

So can I throw all things together? Static cells, Navigation segues and custom backgrounds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey man i post here code hope it will help u

-(void)createTable
{

myTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,132, 320, 350) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

```
myTableView.delegate=self;
myTableView.dataSource=self;
myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.tag=2;
[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
[myTableView release];
```

}
now just call this method  by [self createTable];